# Flex: Syntax error when adding a new rule

Tags: compilation, bison, flex-lexer

My current lex file looks like this:

```
%{
#include "foo.h"
void rem_as(char* string);
%}

DIGIT        [0-9]
LITTERAL     [a-zA-Z]
SEP          [_-]|["."]|["\\"][ ]
FILE_NAME    ({DIGIT}|{LITTERAL}|{SEP})*
PATH         ({FILE_NAME}"/"{FILE_NAME})*|({FILE_NAME})

%%

"move"       {return MOVE;}
"mv"         {return MOVE;}
">"          {return R_STDOUT;}
"2>"         {return R_STDERR;}
"<"          {return R_STDIN;}
"|"          {return PIPE;}
"&"          {return AND;}
"="          {return EQUAL_SIGN;}
"-"?{DIGIT}+ {yylval.integer = atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
{PATH}       {rem_as(yytext); sscanf(yytext,"%[^\n]",yylval.string); return FILENAME;}
\n           {return LINEBREAK;}
. ;

%%
```

That works quite good.
For example, thanks to this grammar

```
Move: MOVE FILENAME FILENAME { move($2, $3); }
    ;
```

I can do stuff like `move a b`.

---

Now my problem:

After adding this to my lex file

```
VAR_NAME     [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*

...

{VAR_NAME}   {return VAR_NAME;} // declared before the "=" rule
```

My previous rules break, especially FILENAME, which now must necessarily contain a '/'.

For example, with this grammar:

```
VarDecl: VAR_NAME EQUAL_SIGN FILENAME { puts("foo"); }
       ;
```

`a=b/` works while `a=b` throws a syntax error.

Any idea about the cause of the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you declare lex rules matters, b matches VAR_NAME, so the VAR_NAME token is emitted, before even trying to match PATH, so you end up with a VAR_NAME EQUAL_SIGN VAR_NAME rule which is invalid.

The easy solution is to make PATH a rule in you grammar, not in your lexical stuff.

PATH: VAR_NAME | FILE_NAME | VAR_NAME SLASH PATH | FILE_NAME SLASH PATH

adding just / as a token in your lex file.

Comment: The solution I chose is to use a token for `var=` thus having no ambiguity, and without changing all my code. Your answer led me to understand the problem so thank you.